# How to specify Python version range in environment.yml file?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Does it make sense to specify range of allowed Python versions in environment.yml file? I got this idea while reading the [Google's Biq Query documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest)

```
Supported Python Versions
Python >= 3.7, < 3.11
```

If this makes sense then what is the right syntax to specify the range in the environment.yml file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Recommendation: Prefer exact version, not range

While there is nothing logically incorrect with specifying a version range for Python, it has the downside of defining a large solution space, which can lead to slow solving. For practical environments, I would recommend specifying the version for `python` through the minor version, e.g., `python=3.9`.

Note that this behavior mostly pertains to central packages that define variants of other packages, like `python`, `r-base`, or `cudatoolkit`. For most other packages, the impact is not as drastic.

## Benchmarking

Here is a simple environment for basic data analysis, with and without the Python version specified.

**so-py39.yaml**

```yaml
name: so-py39
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python ==3.9
  - ipykernel
  - numba
  - pandas
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
```

**so-py3x.yaml**

```yaml
name: so-py3x
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python >=3.7,<4.0
  - ipykernel
  - numba
  - pandas
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
```

### Conda

First, we can use the regular `conda` command.

**Command**

```bash
command time conda env create -dqn foo -f [file]
```

### Results

```bash
Timing creating environment: so-py39.yaml
       20.51 real        19.57 user         0.94 sys
       20.73 real        19.84 user         0.97 sys
       19.43 real        18.66 user         0.95 sys
       19.22 real        18.36 user         0.92 sys
       19.34 real        18.48 user         0.94 sys
       19.08 real        18.16 user         0.94 sys

Timing creating environment: so-py3x.yaml
       30.53 real        29.56 user         1.00 sys
       29.21 real        28.21 user         1.08 sys
       31.13 real        29.77 user         1.07 sys
       29.93 real        28.46 user         0.99 sys
       30.53 real        29.43 user         0.98 sys
       28.60 real        27.68 user         1.03 sys
```

That is, solving for the environment with a range takes ~10s (~50%) longer.

### Mamba

We can also test solving the environment with Mamba.

**Command**

```bash
command time mamba env create -dqn foo -f [file]
```

### Results

```bash
Timing creating environment: so-py39.yaml
        3.30 real         2.79 user         0.49 sys
        3.36 real         2.84 user         0.51 sys
        3.25 real         2.74 user         0.49 sys
        3.34 real         2.82 user         0.51 sys
        3.29 real         2.78 user         0.51 sys
        3.24 real         2.74 user         0.48 sys

Timing creating environment: so-py3x.yaml
        3.27 real         2.79 user         0.47 sys
        3.26 real         2.78 user         0.46 sys
        3.33 real         2.83 user         0.48 sys
        3.28 real         2.79 user         0.47 sys
        3.31 real         2.81 user         0.49 sys
        3.29 real         2.81 user         0.47 sys
```

This indicates that when using Mamba the difference in solve time is neglible.

Comment: I see the logic and point in your statement in specifying the version and not the range. I will stick to it :-) . Thankyou